# What happened to the Google Contacts API documentation?

Tags: api, documentation

Sometime in the last two weeks, the documentation for the Google Contacts API has gone offline. It used to be at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/.

The ContactsAPI does not show up in the newer Google APIs Explorer at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/.

Google is usually really good at announcing deprecations and end-of-life dates for APIs and products, but I can't find anything in their blogs about this API, so I can't tell if this is just a mistake or an intentional change.

The Contacts API itself is still accessible via the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), so it's not actually offline.

We can access the API documentation in Google's cache of the first URL above, but we're nervous about developing against something whose future is unclear!

Does anyone know what happened to this documentation?

Comment: The link is broken on their API directory page, too. I think someone screwed up at their end.

Comment: Seems to be back up now :)  ive been waiting aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never got an explanation, but the documentation is back up as of today. What a relief!

Answer (score 2):

Sbleon, that was really weird for the document offline. But I am using this API in our app and haven't encounter any problem now - so its API is not really offline.  Based on my experience on Google API, even new version come out, it will be highly compatible with the older ones. The only problem of Google Api is Domain-wide/Google Apps  OAuth 2.0 still not available in some APIs.

Comment: agree with Barmar, maybe only a temporarily screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Contacts v3 Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) is Down with **Error 404 PAGE NOT FOUND** for the third day.

Comment: This isn't really an explanation. Could you offer a reason for it being down?